# VB form send an email with form fields within a text file as an attachment

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, email, email-attachments

I'm a newbie to VB forms but needs some advise on if this is possible.  I want to email the form fields as a one line pipe delimited text file attachment. So when you open the email that is sent it will have *.txt file attached and the 1st line will look like this

```
textbox1_value|textbox2_value|textbox3_value
```

here is my email code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using message As New MailMessage()
            'set to the from, to and subject fields
            message.From = New MailAddress(TextBox2.Text.ToString())
            message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("steve@steve.com"))
            message.Subject = "Certificate alert"
            'code the message body
            Dim MsgBody As String
            MsgBody = TextBox2.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                      TextBox3.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                      TextBox4.Text.ToString()
            message.Body = MsgBody
            Dim client As New SmtpClient()
            client.Host = "mailhost"
            client.Send(message)
        End Using
        'display submitted box
        MessageBox.Show("Your Incident has been submitted!", "Congratulations!")
        'close form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the text that belongs in the attachment to a text file, then:

```
message.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("filename"))
system.io.file.delete("filename") ' delete the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your file on disk

```
Dim filename as String = "C:\Somefile.txt"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filename, "value1|value2|value3")
```

Then attach to your mail message:

```
Dim att as New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(filename)
message.Attachments.Add(att)
```

Don't forget to delete your file afterwards

Comment: can i get the code to delete it auto automatically after it has sent ?

Comment: Yeah just google it - or type `My.Computer.FileSystem.` and see what comes up next

Comment: My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filename, "value1|value2|value3")

Comment: [How to: Delete a File in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdx72k4b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)